# Jenkins control on multiple choice parameter to list the apps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement in Jenkins as below.

1) Select environment in choice parameter i.e. prod/staging/sit
2) Based on the above environment value, I need to run execute .SH file to fetch the list of deployed applications from my runtime.
3) Populate the retrieved data again in to a choice parameter and allow user to submit  for any start/stop action.

Is it possible in Jenkins to trigger an action based on user selected value in choice parameter? something like AJAX....

Answer (score 0):

it is possible in Jenkins to do a choice active based choices.

you need to add a parameter named "Active Choices Reactive Parameter"

in this parameter there is a field named "Referenced Parameter",
whenever this value is changed the Parameter get's reevaluated based on the changed value